# Trouble getting multilingual support to work in PyQT4 program

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, python-2.x

I'm trying to implement multilingual support in a program written in pyqt4. I have all the .qm files, as well as the translator function, however I can't get the `tr` function to work.

Atleast that's what I'm assuming is not working in my code. I set my locale to various things which I have translation files for, but my program doesn't change to reflect this.

I see other people make their programs handle translation by using the `tr` function, however my code was made from QTDesigner, and it already had code that suggests it handles translation, however it doesn't seem to work for me. It looks something like this.

```
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

    ...

    self.welcomeButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Welcome", None))
```

So far I have a setup like this. I have a directory called GUI which contains a file called GUI.py that contains all the QT code. I also have a directory called tr which contains all of my .qm files. Then in the parent directory I have a file called qtrunner.py which I use to tie it all together.

The relevant code for qtrunner.py. This is where I call GUI.py and run the translator.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from GUI import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

    locale = QtCore.QLocale.system().name()
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)
    translator.load('/usr/share/turbulence/tr/qt_%s.qm' % locale.split("_")[0], QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
    app.installTranslator(translator)

    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This is the relevant code for GUI.py.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

...

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

...

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.welcome.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Welcome", None))
```

Like I said, I don't feel that the translator code in qtrunner.py is malfunctioning, but I do think that the `QtGui.QApplication.translate` and the `retranslateUi` function qtdesigner supplied is what's making my code not work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you not already get a copy/pasteble answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757952/how-do-you-implement-multilingual-support-for-pyqt4

Comment: @LaszloPapp No, because I can't implement that into my code. I got the translator working which you can see above, but the translate function being used on the strings doesn't seem to be working. I would like some help using the translate function correctly, since how it is right now doesn't work.

Comment: @josh. There could be any number of reasons why your translations "don't work", but I'm absolutely certain it has nothing to to do with the files generated by pyuic. I have outlined the how the translation process works in my answer below. Please make sure you have followed _all_ the steps correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tr` and `trUtf8` functions are simple wrappers that ultimately call the static function [QCoreApplication.translate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#translate). The pyuic tool emulates this when processing designer files: it generates boiler-plate functions that wrap the same `translate` function.

The `tr` function (and its equivalents) serve two purposes. At runtime, they look up the static strings from the source code and replace them with the appropriate translated strings from the `qm` files. But at *compile time*, they are simply static delimiters that allow tools like `pylupdate` to identify which strings in the source code need translations.

The `pylupdate` tool generates a `*.ts` file, which is an xml representation of the parsed source code. The `ts` files can be read by tools like [Qt Linguist](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-manual.html), which provides a GUI frontend for doing the actual translation of the strings. Once the translations are complete, the `lrelease` tool can be used to compile the `qm` files that are used at runtime.

It's important to understand that there are *two* sets of strings (or "messages") that need translating at runtime. There's the set of *built-in* strings that come from the Qt libraries (e.g. the "Ok", "Cancel", "Yes", "No", strings used by the [Standard Buttons](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html#StandardButton-enum)). And then there's the set of *application-specific* strings that come from your own source code.

The built-in strings would normally be translated using the `qm` files that are installed along with the Qt libraries. From my [previous answer on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20766936/984421), the translator for the built-in strings would be installed like this:

```
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)
    translator.load('qt_%s' % locale,
                    QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(
                        QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
    app.installTranslator(translator)
```

And the translator for the application-specific strings would be installed like this:

```
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)
    translator.load('path/to/my/translations.qm')
    app.installTranslator(translator)
```

See the [documentation for QTranslator.load](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtranslator.html#load) for alternative ways to specify the location of the `qm` file.

Comment: Thank you again, but I'm pretty sure all the above is working. I believe it is a problem with the code QTDesigner supplied to translate the strings. I appreciate all of your help this far though.

Comment: Nevermind, I actually just figured it out! the problem was with the line `class Ui_MainWindow(object):` I had to change it to `class Ui_MainWindow(QtCore.QObject):`.