# Proper way to grab environments locale in python

Tags: python, pyqt, environment-variables, multilingual, python-2.x

I'm writing a program to support localization in PyQT4, and the way that's been suggested to me, is like below.

```
locale = QtCore.QLocale.system().name()
```

Now I'm not sure of this, but I imagine that this somehow grabs the environmental variable `LC_ALL`, which for me regardless of what I set my locale to is always `c`. I can tell that it tries to set `locale` to `c` when I `print` the contents of `locale`

However, when I set my locale, the environmental variable `LANG` is always set to what I set my locale to.

So, my alternative way of grabbing the locale, was just grabbing the environmental variable `LANG` instead of the QT way. This way seems to be much more efficient, and works better for me, but there might be something I'm missing.

```
import os
locale = os.environ['LANG']
```

Can anyone think of any problems with this way, or or reasons why the other way is better?

Edit:
I just found the `locale` module, while searching around. I think this may be a better alternative to either of them.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: If the "suggestion" you're referring to is from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20766936/984421), then I should clarify that it was just copy/pasted from an example in the Qt docs. It does not mean that I was recommending it as the "right" way to do things.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes I was referring to that answer, but I was not trying to take a shot at you if that's what you're inferring. I'm actually very appreciative of the help you've given me this far you helped me very much, but that part of the code is the only part holding me back, so I wanted to make sure I was either not using it right, or if my way was better.

Comment: Thanks, but no: I wasn't really implying anything. I just wanted to point out that QLocale might not be the best option.

Comment: However, when I set my locale, the environmental variable LANG is always set to what I set my locale to. What do you mean by this?

Comment: @lovePython I mean, if I change my locale to say spanish, it sets the environmental variable `LANG` to `es_ES.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***From edit to question by Josh***:

I just found the `locale` module, while searching around. I think this may be a better alternative to either of them.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```